# Just first element within a list after selected radio

Tags: css, queryselector

I've got a sequence of radio button and then other dom-elements. Now I want to hide every element except the one right after the selected radio button.

```html
  <div id="gallery" data-role="image-slider">
        <input type="radio" />
        <div class="image-slider-element">
            <img src="" />
        </div>

        <input type="radio" />
        <div class="image-slider-element">
            <img src="" />
        </div>

        <input type="radio" checked="checked" />
        <div class="image-slider-element">
            <img src="" />
        </div>

        <input type="radio" />
        <div class="image-slider-element">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
[data-role="image-slider"] > input[type="radio"] ~ .image-slider-element {
    display: none;
}

[data-role="image-slider"] > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .image-slider-element {
    display: block;
}

[data-role="image-slider"] img {
    height: 400px;
}
```

The problem is, that (in this case) not only the 3rd element will be displayed, but the 4th anyway. So any idea, how I just can display that element right after the checked one and not all after this?

`[data-role="image-slider"] > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .image-slider-element:first-child` will not work, because `first-child` will relate only to the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - sorry... long day... `+` will work

```css
[data-role="image-slider"] > input[type="radio"]:checked + .image-slider-element {
    display: block;
}
```